# Query for children with few siblings and parents with many children in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two document types, **group** and **item**, which are related through a parent-child mapping. I'm trying to write a query that returns both:

- groups that have more that 10 items
- items that belong to a group with less than 10 items

So results would look something like:

```
1. item
2. group of 12 items
3. item
4. item
5. item
6. group of 34 items
7. item
```

The pseudo query looks like this:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      query_for_items_in_groups_of_fewer_than_10,
      query_for_groups_with_10_or_more_items
    ]
  }
}
```

I have this working as intended, but it's very slow:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "item",
          "min_children": 10,
          "query": SOME_QUERY
        }
      },
      {
        "filtered": {
          "query": SOME_QUERY,
          "filter": {
            "not": {
              "has_parent": {
                "type": "group",
                "query": {
                  "has_child": {
                    "type": "item",
                    "min_children": 10,
                    "query": SOME_QUERY
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a more performant way of doing this? Or perhaps an entirely different approach I could take to grouping items?